# Eliminating index.php from URL in Joomla 2.5

Tags: joomla

I am using Joomla 2.5. The problem is, every link has 'index.php', like:

www.mysite.com/index.php/contact

www.mysite.com/index.php/about-us

How do i remove the '.../index.php/...' from my URLs?

My SEO settings under Global Configuration are:

```
==================================
Search Engine Friendly URLs Yes

Use Apache mod_rewrite Yes

Adds Suffix to URL No

Unicode Aliases No

Include Site Name in Page Titles No
==================================
```

I have changed htaccess.txt to .htaccess. I have tried everything, but still can't remove 'index.php' from the URLs. Please help me. My apologies if this exists elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

**Go into your Joomla administration panel.**

```
1. Select Site > Global Configuration
2. Under SEO Settings set Use URL Rewriting to Yes
3. Click Save
```

The next step is to rename the htaccess.txt file that came with the installation to .htaccess

thats it. Hope this helps .

Answer (score 0):

Did you change the setting on the administrator backend or the actual configuration file? Sometimes if you directly modify the configuration.php this wont work. If you did it from backend panel then check your configuration.php to make sure the changes are reflecting.

Also check with your hosting to have mod_rewrite available on the Apache server.

Very unlikely but it could be a small mistake on renaming process of the htaccess.txt , double check the renamed file.